# Is there a way of accepting multiple types for one argument?

Tags: rust

Is there a way of accepting multiple types for one argument, or having two optional arguments where one is `None` and the other must be satisfied?

An example would be combining these functions into one:

```rust
fn print_range(range: Range<i32>) {
    for i in range {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}

fn print_range_inclusive(range_inclusive: RangeInclusive<i32>) {
    for i in range_inclusive {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`Range<T>` and `RangeInclusive<T>` both implement `Iterator<T>`, so you could make your method generic over `impl Iterator<Item = i32>`:

```
fn print_range(range: impl Iterator<Item = i32>) {
    for i in range {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since all you do is iterate over the argument, you want to take an implementor of the `Iterator` trait. You can think of traits in Rust as being like interfaces in Java; they combine common functionality and allow polymorphism controlled by what a type is capable of, not how it's implemented.

```
use std::fmt::Display;

fn print_range<I, T>(iter: I)
where I: Iterator<Item=T>,
      T: Display {
  for i in iter {
    println!("{}", i);
  }
}
```

What we're saying here is "I want any type which is an iterator `I` and whose item `T` can be displayed to the screen".